# Different between autoungrabify and autolock in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am a beginner with cytoscape.js. I am reading the API documents.
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/documentation/md/core/init.md

My question is what is the difference between "autoungrabify" and "autolock" in the options?

Thanks.

autoungrabify : Whether nodes should be ungrabified (not grabbable by user) by default (if true, overrides individual node state).
autolock : Whether nodes should be locked (not draggable at all) by default (if true, overrides individual node state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ungrabified: A *user* can not grab & move the node
- Locked: The node's position can't be changed at all (e.g. when you're moving nodes programmatically)